# Sass border shorthand with default has wrong order

Tags: css, sass

As a homework I got an assignment to convert some tedious CSS to SASS. The shorter SASS the better. So I tried to use mixin EVERYWHERE. And I have problem with border mixin:

```
=border($border-color, $weight: 1px, $style: solid)
  border: $weight $style $border-color
```

But I have problem. When using just +border($border-color) in CSS I have correct syntax, border: 1px solid black. But when I had to change some values, and use +border(3px, dotted, $border-color), CSS shorthand is messed up, and looks like this: border: dotted #164faa 3px. Is there a way to correct this? How sass decide the order in that case?

Comment: The values come out in the exact order specified. You use `+border(3px, dotted, $border-color)`, and it outputs `border: second_arg third_arg first_arg;` as instructed. The solution, of course, is to use the args in the order they are expected in.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch this... This mixin is useless then, as it's rather unintuitive.

Comment: You can always give all the arguments default values, and then you can put them in the right order. `=border($weight:1px, $style:solid, $color:currentColor)`...